# C# Edit last item in listbox without having it selected

Tags: c#, listbox

I am trying to edit the last item in a listbox without having it selected. Because I can't select items in the list (this is my default for my application). It's a Windows Form Application.

Normally I would do something like: `listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex] + " -> This string is added"` but because I can't select anything, this won't work.

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: WinForms? WFP? ASP.NET?

Comment: If ListBox.Items is a collection, you can loop over them or use Linq to select the last one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get last item from `Items` collection by index:

```
listBox1.Items[listBox1.Items.Count - 1] + " -> This string is added";
```

Comment: @GuidoVisser keep in mind, that if it is possible that list will be empty, this code will throw index out of range exception, so you need to verify if `listBox1.Items.Count > 0` in this case